# как реализовать изображение css (отмечено )

Tags: html, css

Как реализовать данные границы между блоками сайта,подскажите.
[image: Исходниик]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#wrapper{
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          Тут ваш блок
       </div>
  </div>
```

Добавляйте

```
   box-sizing:border-box;
```

если родителю задаете ширину иначе может вылезти за границы экрана.

Подробнее про свойство **box-sizing** можно почитать тут:
http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы использовали id, а не класс? Вопрос же про «⁠⁠границы между блоками сайта», блоков может быть более одного, а id вроде как один раз можно использовать.

Comment: Для наглядности. Если рамки нужны только по бокам, как на вашем изображении, то лучше использовать один глобальный блок.

Comment: На моем изображении? Нет, я не автор вопроса, просто проходил мимо и заинтересовался.

Comment: Извините, не обратил внимания :)

Answer (score -2):

Тут несколько вариантов один уже указали, путем указания значения border. Другой вариант это margin если задний фон имеет цвет.

```css
  *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  body{
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
  }
  p{
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>img</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```